# UDP port scanning

Tags: firewall, port, udp, icmp

UDP is connectionless, so I can't expect a response packet, necessarily. If the port is closed, I might get an ICMP error message, but if the firewall could silently drop the ICMP packet How could I know if the UDP port is opened or closed is there another way to scan UDP port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nmap](http://nmap.org/) tool has the `-sU` flag to scan UDP ports.

e.g :

```
# nmap -sU 192.168.0.39

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-23 19:02 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.39
Host is up (0.00017s latency).
Not shown: 999 open|filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
137/udp open  netbios-ns
MAC Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 19.88 seconds
```

Comment: seems good, but how can I use it in my java code, and retrieve list of open ports ?

Comment: You were not talking about any Java code in your initial question ! However Java is able to run external programs http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html Search for "java run external program" within Google, and post on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) if you have programming problems